# assigning a tuple to a class member variable

Tags: c++, stdtuple

I have a C++ class where I have a tuple which contains some image data and the image dimensions. I have typedef-ed it as follows:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <memory>

typedef std::tuple<std::unique_ptr<unsigned char[]>, int, int> ImageType;
```

Now in my class I have a method and I also have a member of `ImageType`:

```
void setImage(ImageType image)
```

However, when I assign a tuple to my member variable tuple I get the following error:

```
error: use of deleted function 'std::unique_ptr<_Tp [], _Dp>& std::unique_ptr<_Tp [], _Dp>::operator=(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp [], _Dp>&) [with _Tp = unsigned char; _Dp = std::default_delete<unsigned char []>]'
  _M_head(*this) = _M_head(__in);
```

A demo program follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <tuple>

typedef std::tuple<std::unique_ptr<unsigned char[]>, int, int> ImageType;

class DataModel
{

public:
    void setImage(ImageType image)
    {
        myImage = image;
    }

    ImageType myImage;
};

int main()
{
  std::unique_ptr<unsigned char[]> ptr(new unsigned char[100]);    
  ImageType im = std::make_tuple(std::move(ptr), 10, 10);
  DataModel dm;
  dm.setImage(im);

  return 0;
}
```

You can also try to compile this online here: [cpp.sh/5chnn](http://cpp.sh/5chnn)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your `tuple` contains a `unique_ptr` it is non-copyable so you could do the following

```
void setImage(ImageType image)
{
    myImage = std::move(image);
}
```

Then to call it

```
DataModel dm;
dm.setImage(std::move(im));
```

or just directly

```
DataModel dm;
dm.setImage(std::make_tuple(std::move(ptr), 10, 10));
```

Comment: Why use rvalue reference instead of non-reference?

Comment: That would be fine too, then you'd just have to `std::move` within the setter to assign to the member variable.

Comment: @CoryKramer Thanks for the reply. I tried this but got the same error: cpp.sh/3ssql

Comment: @Luca Try the edited version that simply passes by value, [that will work fine](http://cpp.sh/247py)

Comment: Don't we still need to move when passing by rvalue reference?

Comment: @CoryKramer Thanks that does work. Why did the previous version not work though?

Comment: @underscore_d yes. `image` is a name, so it is an lvalue. @Luca because of what we're discussing. The move within `setImage` was missing.

Comment: @jdehesa [It does](http://cpp.sh/5s2p3) you just forgot to `std::move` the `std::unique_ptr` within the `std::make_tuple` call